# Login to remote site with PHP cURL and fetch site data

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from https://www.manheim.com as logged in user. I have implemented the same for cpanel and working with all cpanel, but not working for this site. Please help me to do the same. I am fetching authenticity_token by inspecting the login page. I will grab it automatically by scraping after implementing successful login.

Code for cpanel :

```
$url="http://example.com:2082/login/?login_only=1"; 
$pass = 'pass';

$postinfo = "user=user";
$postinfo .= "&pass=".$pass;
$postinfo .= "&submit=Login";

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
$login = curl_exec($ch);

$login = json_decode($login);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com:2082". $login->redirect);
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($html);
```

Code for manheim.com

```
$url ="https://www.manheim.com/login/authenticate"; 
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $path . "/cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "utf8=✓&authenticity_token=vsB5lCaB0rumkZxm940HWgMxSecpsjDXMGJxYHDbU5g=&user[username]=user&user[password]=pass&submit=Login"); 
ob_start();      
curl_exec ($ch); 
ob_end_clean();  
curl_close ($ch); 
unset($ch); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $path . "/cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.manheim.com/members/powersearch/keywordSearchResults.do?searchTerms=WA1CNAFY1J2000316"); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch); 
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your cpanel code, username and password is not urlencoded, so if they contain `&` or `=` or spaces or tabs or `ÆØÅ` or a bunch of other characters, you'll send the wrong credentials, and won't get logged in. it's just because you were lucky and your password didn't contain any special characters, that your cpanel login code ever worked, fix that with urlencode() while you're at it. also, don't use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST for GET requests (use CURLOPT_HTTPGET instead, but that's the default mode anyway), nor for POST requests (use CURLOPT_POST instead). as for manheim.com , seems you do the same urlencode mistake as with cpanel. but more importantly, your authenticity_token is hardcoded. that's never going to work, that authenticity_token is tied to your browser, unique to your browser's session cookie id, and probably expired long ago. hardcoding it won't work. instead, make a GET request to https://www.manheim.com/ , in the headers you'll get an unique session cookie id, you must send this cookie in all future requests, because if you don't, it'll be like switching a browser, and this website is weird, **if you don't already have a cookie session id, you can't see the login page, if you try, you'll get http-header-redirected to a bogus url**, then make a GET request with the cookie id to https://www.manheim.com/login/ , then in the html, you'll get an unique authenticity_token tied to your cookie session id. parse out the authenticity_token from the html, and add them to the POST body of your next request to `https://www.manheim.com/login/authenticate`, together with the static data (username & password & submit), and make sure they're all urlencoded, then you should get logged in. and to continue to get the logged in page, keep sending the same cookie session id, because your login is tied to that id, and if you don't send it, the web server won't remember that you're logged in, and you'll get some "you need to login to see this page" error.

here's an example implementation (using the hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php as a convenience wrapper around curl_ functions, turning silent errors into exceptions, handling cookies, and a lot more)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
hhb_init(); // better error reporting
const USERNAME = '?';
const PASSWORD = '??';
$hc = new hhb_curl ( '', true );

header ( "content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8" );
$hc->exec ( 'https://www.manheim.com/' ); // getting a cookie session id
$html = $hc->exec ( 'https://www.manheim.com/login/' )->getResponseBody (); // getting authenticity_token , required for logging in
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
$token = $xp->query ( '//input[@name="authenticity_token"]' )->item ( 0 )->getAttribute ( "value" );
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.manheim.com/login/authenticate',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'utf8' => '✓',
                'authenticity_token' => $token,
                'user' => array (
                        'username' => USERNAME,
                        'password' => PASSWORD 
                ),
                'submit' => 'Login' 
        ) ) 
) )->exec ();
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
$errmsg = $xp->query ( '//*[contains(@class,"msgError")]' );
if ($errmsg->length > 0) {
    echo 'Error logging in: ' . $errmsg->item ( 0 )->textContent;
} else {
    echo 'logged in!';
}
hhb_var_dump ( $token, $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
```

right now, it prints: 
`Error logging in: 
      The username and password you entered do not match any accounts on record. Please make sure that you have correctly entered your username and password. Both are case-sensitive and should not contain any special characters. If you have forgotten your username or password, please use our username retrieval or password retrieval tools.`

but if you change out the username and password on line 4 and 5, it will probably log in instead, and say `logged in!` (then print a bunch of debug data)

- ps, in the code above, i used `http_build_query` instead of urlencode() to do the urlencoding. when there's several variables to encode, giving an array to a single http_build_query call will often result in prettier code than manually urlencode()'ing everything :)

Comment: Only working in php 7,  any suggestion for lower version?

Comment: @BinodSarkar sure, remove the `declare(strict_types = 1);` line, and replace `require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');` with `require_once ('hhb_.inc.php5.php');` from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php5.php - now it should work in PHP5 - that said, PHP7's scalar type hints is a blessing, you really should upgrade to PHP7 if you can :)